# Button user control with Dependency property ShowImage display image path instead of Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a button user control which can display Image from xaml by adding property (ShowImage="ImagePath").
I've bound the user control Image source to the button's Content in the xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testUserControl.UserControls.TestDependencyShowImage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <Grid>
        <Button MinHeight="30" MinWidth="50">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I've created a Dependency property which create BitmapImage and set it to the content(in the meantime hard coded path just to see if it can be done).

cs:

```
namespace testUserControl.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestDependencyShowImage.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestDependencyShowImage : UserControl
    {
        private static BitmapImage  s_oImage            = null;
        private static string       s_strSourceImage    = null;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowImageDP = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowImage", typeof(string), typeof(TestDependencyShowImage), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(SetImage)));

        public string ShowImage
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ShowImageDP);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ShowImageDP, value);
                this.Content = s_oImage;
                //OnTargetPowerChanged(this, new DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs(TargetPowerProperty, value, value));    // Old value irrelevant.
            }
        }

        private static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            TestDependencyShowImage muc = (TestDependencyShowImage)obj;
            s_strSourceImage = (string)args.NewValue;
            if (s_strSourceImage != null)
            {
                s_oImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\AmitL\Desktop\james-brown-010.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                //BitmapImage l_oImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value));
            }

        }


        public TestDependencyShowImage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = s_oImage;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: no image!]

Comment: There are many things wrong here. First of all, you must not set the UserControl's `Content` property in code-behind, because that replaces everything that was created by its XAML. The Content of the UserControl contains the top-level Grif from its XAML, and you won't change that. That said, the `{TemplateBinding Content}` in the Button's ControlTemplate refers to the Button's Content, not the one of the UserControl.

Comment: Next, you must never do anything else than GetValue/SetValue in the CLR wrappers of dependency properties. All necessary code that should be called in response to a changed property value should be in the PropertyChangedCallback. See [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) for more details.

Comment: And if it is all about creating a Button with an Image as its Content, then why not do exactly that? Create a Button, and set its Content property to a BitmapImage. No UserControl required.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need any of that code. Just let the Framework convert the `string` file path into the image for you. Try this code inside your `UserControl`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ShowImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXamlNamespacePrefix:TestDependencyShowImage}}}" />
```